# Variable names: How to abbreviate "index"?

Tags: variables, language-agnostic

I like to keep the names of my variables short but readable.

Still, when, for example, naming the variable that holds the index of an element in some list, I tend to use `elemIndex` because I don't know a proper (and universally understood) way of abbreviating the word "index".

Is there a canonic way of abbreviating "index"? Or is it best to spell it in full to avoid misunderstandings?

Comment: Never assume another developer will understand your abbreviations. For the sake of humanity, spell them out.

Comment: @BradM: So using `Idx` like Alan does is also a bad idea?

Comment: @mareser If you are being strict about it, then yes it's a bad idea. I tend to only abbreviate things which are really long, or should be readily apparent from context, and in either case comment the first/key occurrence(s) of said abbreviation within a section. In practice, while avoiding abbreviation is a good rule of thumb, there is a point at which doing so can adversely effect the readability of your code (and increase typo rates). It's a matter of judgement... or sticking to your organizations style guide.

Comment: We should use canonical abbreviations. It's standard in fact. js for JavaScript, h-file in C++, I for interfaces, Impl for Implementation in C#/Java, idx for db (databases), i,j,k for indexes in `for`, and so on. And like in real live, we should avoid abbreviation that are not very common, or at least we should document them and use one standard for company or a big project.
But we should prefer more precise (and so, more long) names for more global variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my experience it depends on the context. Typically I can tell if something is an index from what it is used for, so I am often more interested in knowing what it is an index of.

My rule of thumb goes roughly like this:

If it is just a loop index in a short loop (e.g.: all fits on screen at once) and the context informs the reader what the index is doing, then you can probably get away with something simple like `i`.

Example: thresholding an image

```
//For each pixel in the image, threshold it
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++ ) {
  for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    if (image[i][j] < 128) {
      image[i][j] = 0;
    } else {
      image[i][j] = 255;
    }
  }
}
```

If the code section is larger, or you have multiple indeces going on, indicate which list it is an index into:

```
File[] files_in_dir = ...;
int num_files = files_in_dir.length();
for (int fileIdx = 0; fileIdx < num_files; fileIdx++) { //for each file in dir.
  ...
}
```

If, however the index is actually important to the meaning of the code, then specify it fully, for example:

```
int imageToDeleteIdx = 3; //index of the image to be deleted.
image_list.delete(imageToDeleteIdx);
```

However code should be considered "write once, read many" and your effort should be allocated as such; i.e.: lots on the writing, so the reading is easy. To this end, as was mentioned by Brad M, never assume the reader understands your abbreviations. If you are going to use abbreviations, at least declare them in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Stick to established and well known conventions. If you use common conventions, people will have fewer surprises when they read your code.

Programmers are used to using a lot of conventions from mathematics. E.g. in mathematics we typically label indices:

```
i, j, k
```

While e.g. coordinates are referred to with letters such as:

```
x, y, z
```

This depends of course on  context. E.g. using *i* to denote some global index would be a **terrible** idea. Use short names for very local variables and longer names for more global functions and variables, is a good rule of thumb.

For me this style was influenced by Rob Pike, who elaborates more on this [here](http://doc.cat-v.org/bell_labs/pikestyle). As someone with an interest in user interface design and experience I've also written more extensively about this.